# How does Vedanta differentiate between reflected consciouness(Chidabhasa) and pure consciouness(Chit)?

Tags: advaita, vedanta, upanishads, consciousness, chit

Pure consciousness is said to be the source of reflected consciousness. How does Vedanta try to separate the mixture of mind and reflected consciousness from pure consciousness and establish the "I" refers to pure consciousness but not the "ahamkara" or "ego" of the mind?